# Having trouble compiling ffmpeg code in command terminal

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am having a bit of trouble compiling my c++ code in my terminal. I have ffmpeg installed as shown below.

```
ffmpeg version n4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-small --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libshine --enable-libsmbclient --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-libmysofa --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libdrm
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

However, when I compile my c++ code, currently trying to get NTP timestamps from private data in ffmpeg but I need to include their headers? I have looked into ffmpeg's `libavformat` folder and it does have `rtpdec.h` but when I compile it in the command line, i get this error. (trying to include this header for `RTSPState` and `RTSPStream` as well as `RTPDemuxContext`)

```
cf.cpp:11:10: fatal error: libavformat/rtsp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libavformat/rtpdec.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavformat/avio.h>
#include <libavformat/rtpdec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Open the initial context variables that are needed
    SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
    AVFormatContext* format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = NULL;
    int video_stream_index;
    uint32_t* last_rtcp_ts;
    double* base_time;
    double* time;

    // Register everything
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    //open RTSP
    if (avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, "rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.67:554",
            NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(format_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //search video stream
    for (int i = 0; i < format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (format_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            video_stream_index = i;
    }

    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);

    //open output file
    AVFormatContext* output_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

    AVStream* stream = NULL;
    int cnt = 0;

    //start reading packets from stream and write them to file
    av_read_play(format_ctx);    //play RTSP

    // Get the codec
    AVCodec *codec = NULL;
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
        exit(1);
    }

// Add this to allocate the context by codec
codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

avcodec_get_context_defaults3(codec_ctx, codec);
avcodec_copy_context(codec_ctx, format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec);
std::ofstream output_file;

if (avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, NULL) < 0)
    exit(1);

    img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height,
            codec_ctx->pix_fmt, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
            SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    int size = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, codec_ctx->width,
            codec_ctx->height);
    uint8_t* picture_buffer = (uint8_t*) (av_malloc(size));
    AVFrame* picture = av_frame_alloc();
    AVFrame* picture_rgb = av_frame_alloc();
    int size2 = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codec_ctx->width,
            codec_ctx->height);
    uint8_t* picture_buffer_2 = (uint8_t*) (av_malloc(size2));
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) picture, picture_buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
            codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height);
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) picture_rgb, picture_buffer_2, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
            codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height);

    while (av_read_frame(format_ctx, &packet) >= 0 && cnt < 1000) { //read ~ 1000 frames

        RTSPState* rt = format_ctx->priv_data;
        RTSPStream *rtsp_stream = rt->rtsp_streams[0];
        RTPDemuxContext* rtp_demux_context = rtsp_stream->transport_priv;
        uint32_t new_rtcp_ts = rtp_demux_context->last_rtcp_timestamp;
        uint64_t last_ntp_time = 0;

        if (new_rtcp_ts != *last_rtcp_ts) {
            *last_rtcp_ts = new_rtcp_ts;
            last_ntp_time = rtp_demux_context->last_rtcp_ntp_time;
            uint32_t seconds = ((last_ntp_time >> 32) & 0xffffffff) - 2208988800;
            uint32_t fraction  = (last_ntp_time & 0xffffffff);
            double useconds = ((double) fraction / 0xffffffff);
            *base_time = seconds + useconds;
            uint32_t d_ts = rtp_demux_context->timestamp - *last_rtcp_ts;
            *time = *base_time + d_ts / 90000.0;
            std::cout << "Time is: " << *time << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "1 Frame: " << cnt << std::endl;
        if (packet.stream_index == video_stream_index) {    //packet is video
            std::cout << "2 Is Video" << std::endl;
            if (stream == NULL) {    //create stream in file
                std::cout << "3 create stream" << std::endl;
                stream = avformat_new_stream(output_ctx,
                        format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec->codec);
                avcodec_copy_context(stream->codec,
                        format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec);
                stream->sample_aspect_ratio =
                        format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codec->sample_aspect_ratio;
            }
            int check = 0;
            packet.stream_index = stream->id;
            std::cout << "4 decoding" << std::endl;
            int result = avcodec_decode_video2(codec_ctx, picture, &check, &packet);
            std::cout << "Bytes decoded " << result << " check " << check
                    << std::endl;
            if (cnt > 100)    //cnt < 0)
                    {
                sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, picture->data, picture->linesize, 0,
                        codec_ctx->height, picture_rgb->data, picture_rgb->linesize);
                std::stringstream file_name;
                file_name << "test" << cnt << ".ppm";
                output_file.open(file_name.str().c_str());
                output_file << "P3 " << codec_ctx->width << " " << codec_ctx->height
                        << " 255\n";
                for (int y = 0; y < codec_ctx->height; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < codec_ctx->width * 3; x++)
                        output_file
                                << (int) (picture_rgb->data[0]
                                        + y * picture_rgb->linesize[0])[x] << " ";
                }
                output_file.close();
            }
            cnt++;
        }
        av_free_packet(&packet);
        av_init_packet(&packet);
    }
    av_free(picture);
    av_free(picture_rgb);
    av_free(picture_buffer);
    av_free(picture_buffer_2);

    av_read_pause(format_ctx);
    avio_close(output_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(output_ctx);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The command i use to compile my code: `g++ -w cf.cpp -o cf $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libavformat libswscale libavcodec)`

I am a bit new to coding in FFmpeg.

Comment: The error message is inconsistent. It says that `rtsp.h` was not found, while the include states that you want to include `rtpdec.h`. Make sure that you are building everything from scratch.

Comment: I built from source, however, I don't know why it's like this. Should I rebuild again? This is a bit confusing to me. A bit strange though, `avio.h` and `avformat.h` are found and `rtpdec.h` isn't.

Comment: I mean your project. I don't know what IDE and build system you are using, but try to delete whatever cached data there is, make sure all files are written to disk, restart IDE, etc. The error message makes no sense as it is right now. It seems that the compiled `cf.cpp` is not the current one.

Comment: I am just compiling on my ubuntu terminal. I will try using an IDE or something. A bit puzzled. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No need for an IDE, just make a test file containing `#include <libavformat/rtpdec.h>` and see if that gives the same error message. I suspect it won't and you are somehow not compiling the file that you intend to. But let me know if I am wrong and that test fails with the same error message.

Comment: Just did a quick test like you said, it still brought up the same error.  I think Ill rebuild ffmpeg and see what happens after that.

Comment: You state `"I have looked into ffmpeg's libavformat folder and it does have rtpdec.h"` -- what is the full path to that file?  Is it part of the installation or private to the `ffmpeg` repository?

Comment: The full path to the file would be this `/home/mick/FFmpeg/libavformat/rtpdec.h`. It is a part of the installation, not sure if it is private to ffmpeg's repo. I installed it as a custom debian package ( followed this [blog](https://seanthegeek.net/455/how-to-compile-and-install-ffmpeg-4-0-on-debian-ubuntu/)). Something tells me it may be private to ffmpeg's repo since I installed it as a custom debian package.

Comment: what's the output of this "**pkg-config --cflags --libs libavformat libswscale libavcodec**" in your terminal.

Comment: `-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lswscale -lavcodec`. This is what I got